# How to check if a Script defines a particular Class or Property using MSScriptControl?

Tags: vb6, msscriptcontrol

I'm currently idiot-proofing a legacy VB6 program that uses an `MSScriptControl`. It takes a file name as input, then gets some strings defined in a `Property` of a `Class` defined in said file.

Here's the current code:

```
Dim oScript As New ScriptControl
With oScript
    .Language = "VBSCRIPT"
    .Reset
    .UseSafeSubset = False
    .Timeout = -1

    sScriptCode = "ScriptLoadedFromSomeFileDefinedSomewhereElse" 'This variable contains the entire length of the script file

    'This Len() should guard against Test:FileIsBlank
    If Len(sScriptCode) = 0 Then GoTo DoTheRest

    'This InStr() should guard against Test:FileDoesNotContainClassDef
    If InStr(1, sScriptCode, "Class myClassName", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then GoTo DoTheRest

    .AddCode sScriptCode
    .AddCode "Dim myClassName"
    .AddCode "Set myClassObject = New myClassName"

    'These InStr()s should guard against Test:FileDoesNotContainExpectedSubs
    If InStr(1, sScriptCode, "Property Get PropStringA", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then GoTo DoTheRest
    sPropStringA = .Eval("myClassObject.PropStringA")

    If InStr(1, sScriptCode, "Property Get PropStringB", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then GoTo DoTheRest
    sPropStringB = .Eval("myClassObject.PropStringB")

    'This should guard against everything else. That is, Test:FileContainsInvalidVBCode
    If Err Then GoTo DoTheRest
End With

DoTheRest:
'Rest of Code
```

Here's the pertinent part of the input script file:

```
Class myClassName

Public Property Get PropStringA()
  PropStringA = _
    "StringA" 
End Property

Public Property Get PropStringB()
  PropStringB = _
    "StringB,StringC,StringD,StringE"
End Property
```

The above is loaded into the `sScriptCode` variable via `FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile()`.

The entire purpose of using `ScriptControl` is to get the strings defined in the file's Class Properties `PropStringA` and `PropStringB`, by instantiating the `Class` and using `ScriptControl.Eval`.

**Here's my question**: this (hack) works, but is there a better, more refined way for me to check that the input script actually contains the things I need, specifically a `Class` definition and `Public Get Property`(ies)? What about if the file is not blank but doesn't actually contain VB code, say, a text file?

Bonus: Should I have asked this over on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it **does** seem more suited to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Should I just make a new question there or could this one be migrated over?